# Keyboard not responding in Spyder on remote Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, keyboard, xrandr, xrdp, spyder

The Spyder installed on the server through Anaconda is not detecting any keyboard inputs. The server is connected on my local machine through xrdp.
I've tried following:

`export XKB_DEFAULT_RULES=base
 export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb`

But it didn't help either.

The only error i'm getting now is:

> QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
>
> Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.

I have vnc4server being used.

Please help.

Thanks